# Why did Arthur Kipps have to go to the village?

Tags: movie, the-woman-in-black

In **The Woman in Black** why did Arthur Kipps have to travel to the village in the first place?

How did the London Office find out about

> all the papers in the house wouldn't the villagers have done everything to cover their existence up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recollection of the film is a little compromised by trying to dissuade my niece and her friend from open warfare over who got to hold the popcorn, but I don't recall any mention of how the law firm knew there were papers at the house. However where there were unresolved issues over a will it would be routine to send someone to search the house for any paperwork that was lying around. As I recall the papers weren't well organised and filed, so it didn't seem as if someone had already been there.

> The villagers believed (rightly!) that any disturbance to the house would raise the spectre and cause children to die, so there wasn't a lot they could do.

Comment: The lawyer in the village seemed to have everything prepared, but the London office still wanted him to travel there.

Comment: I would guess, and obviously it has to be a guess, that the office were unsatisfied with the information from the lawyer in the village (Jerome?). The fact that Kipps found lots more documents at the house suggests Jerome had been fairly cursory. But we're probably reading stuff into what was just a plot device.

Answer (score 0):

the lawyer in the village refused to go to the house and no one local would either because they all knew the suspicion of the woman in black they needed someone who didn't and he was payed extra

Comment: There was no mention in the film of him being paid extra.